# Codename One - get selected text from AutoComplete

Tags: codenameone

How can I get the complete selected text from an AutoComplete TextField?

If I use getText(), I only get the few letters the user has input so far.

Example: I write "flo" and then select "Flowers" from the list, but getText() gives me "flo"

```
AutoCompleteTextField auto = new AutoCompleteTextField(arrayWithNames);
auto.setMinimumLength(4);
auto.addListListener((ActionEvent evt1) -> {
    String lookedFor = auto.getText();
    Hashtable<String,Object> match[] = findMatch(lookedFor);
    if(hMatch.length>0){
        contElements.removeAll();
        for (Hashtable<String, Object> Match1 : match) {
            ...
            ...//fill the Container with the names found
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

**How it works**

I am using the AutoComplete TF as a search button.
I have an array with all the names in my list.
Then I populate the Auto with the array.
The user selects a name from the Auto and then I search the value that is being "lookedFor" using the findMatch(). It returns a new array with the found entries.

I need the complete name from the list so I can use the findMatch() method, but when I use getText() from the Auto, it only returns the letters the user entered, and not the whole name, so my method does not work, since I am comparing whole Strings.
(I am using the Auto because it is very convenient if people remember only a part of the name they are looking for)

Answer (score 1):

If you subclass `AutoCompleteTextField` you can access the selected text internally via `getSuggestionModel().getItemAt(getSuggestionModel().getSelectedIndex())`. Now you can define a `public` getter method `getSelectedText()` or something on your derived class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are using the AutoCompleteTextBox correctly.

The entire purpose of the AutoCompleteText box is to help you assist the user in selecting from a list of valid requests,

You should not be getting the value of `getText()` until the user is ready to submit the form where the AutoCompleteTB is located.

This WILL help if you haven't already looked here:
https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/AutoCompleteTextField.html#getPropertyTypes--

Good luck!

Comment: I did just what you mentioned on your first lines. I have added the Listener to the AutoComplete TF and it does trigger the getText() method when I select an item from the list, but instead of returning the complete selected value from the list, I only get the few letters I pressed on the keyboard: "hou" instead of "House", "pita" instead of "Hospital", etc

Comment: `public void addListListener(ActionListener a)`
Adds an action listener that fires an event when an entry in the auto-complete list is selected. Notice that this method will only take effect when the popup is reshown, if it is invoked when a popup is already showing it will have no effect.

This event will fire when they select an item from the ACTF and then the list model is redrawn to reflect that visibly.  Internally the user will select the input and the TextField contents are updated by ACTF; ie you don;t have to do this yourself.

Comment: Another way would be to use the `keyPress` events and then setup a variable to toggle the key-clicks to determine when the user has selected a auto-complete item, and determine the index of the users selection to grab the auto-complete list model text from `getCompletion()`.

Comment: keyPress won't work since its only for physical keys and not for virtual keyboard entry but action listener is indeed correct and should work.

Comment: I don't understand the virtual key condition.  These events cannot be used to gather keyboard input and process it?

Comment: I can mimic the behaviour of the ACTF using keyPress events and processing the ListModel myself, but this is silly considering the ACTF does all this for you.

Comment: @Felipe  -  You are not using the ACTF correctly.   Can you edit your question to give us more details on the exact implementation that you are hoping to achieve?  What are you trying to do in terms of your application at this point?

Comment: Key in Codename One refers to physical keyboard or keypad. Virtual keyboards as exist in iOS/Android don't send key events as their input is too complex for that level. You can use datachange listener if you want fine grained control over input but in this particular case use the action listener.

Comment: There @zackery.fix  Thanks, and I hope you can fnd my mistake

Comment: I edited my answer.   You are getting the value of `getText()` too early.  Your code will work as expected; but not as intended.  

Does your form have a submit button for the user??

Comment: Yeah, you were right. It was too early. Now I added the submit button and inside its ActionListener added the getText() and it works!!!.  Happy new Year @zackery.fix!